No module named 'fastapi_utils'
I am trying to run FastApi app from this repo: https://github.com/wpcodevo/fastapi_sqlalchemy
My actions:
python3.11 -m ven venv # was trying 3.8 and 3.11
source venv/bin/activate

pip install requirements.txt  
uvicorn app.main:app --reload

I have an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 458, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/44_feast_ui_backend/fastapi_sqlalchemy/./app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import models, note
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/44_feast_ui_backend/fastapi_sqlalchemy/./app/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from fastapi_utils.guid_type import GUID, GUID_DEFAULT_SQLITE
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi_utils'

Error is odd for me, because fastapi_utils was installed
pip list | grep fastapi      
fastapi            0.85.1
fastapi-utils      0.2.1

UPDATE:
found out that I have this error on my PC (macOS 14.5). But I don't have error on another pc (macOS 12.2.1)

Have you tried pip install fastapi-utils?

Yes, sure. Installed successfully

And you still have this error after the installation?
